# If $x,y \in \ell^2$ then $\sum_i x_i y_i < \infty$ proof verification.

Tags: metric-spaces, solution-verification, hilbert-spaces

So, I came across this problem in a textbook with its proof. But I completely disagree on how it was done. Because they used the fact that a normally convergent series is convergent without having the completeness of $\ell^2$ proved and then go on to prove it's completeness using the fact $\sum_i x_i y_i < \infty$.

So, I tried to prove this convergence the following way:

For all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $x < y$ we have
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
    x < y &\implies& \left\{\begin{array}{l}
        x^2 < xy \\
        xy < y^2
    \end{array}\right. \\[0.3cm]
    &\implies& x^2 < xy < y^2.
\end{array}
$$
Then, defining $z=(z_1,\dots,z_i,\dots)$ by $z_i = \max\{x_i,y_i\}$, we get $z \in \ell^2$ and
$$
\sum_i x_i y_i \leq \sum_i z_i^2 < \infty.
$$

So, is this line of reasoning correct? Is there a simpler way to prove this?

And how do I prove rigorously that $z \in \ell^2$?

Comment: A simpler way to prove this is to use the fact that $$x_iy_i \leq \frac{x_i^2 + y_i^2}{2}$$

Comment: And how do I get this inequality?

Comment: Well, just develop from $(x_i - y_i)^2 \geq 0$.

Comment: First, being less than something would only mean it converges if the $x_iy_i$ are positive. You really want $\sum |x_iy_i|$ is convergent.

Comment: $x<y \implies x^2<xy$ is false in general: take $x=-1$ and $y=1$.

Comment: To give a variant of @TheSilverDoe's comment, the easier way to prove the series converges is that it is absolutely convergent, since $$|x_iy_i|\leq\frac{x_i^2+y_i^2}{2}.$$

Comment: Your approach can be made to work, letting $z_i=\max(|x_i|,|y_i|).$ This is because $w_i=\min(|x_i|,|y_i|)$ has $0\leq w_i^2\leq x_i^2$ so $\sum w_i^2$ converges, and thus $z_i^2=x_i^2+y_i^2-w_i^2$ converges.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. One can conclude that this sum is normally convergent on $\mathbb{R}$, so it converges. I got this mixed up with a series of sequences on $\ell^2$ being normally convergent. Thank you.

Comment: By "normally convergent," do you mean "absolutely convergent?"

Comment: And I did define $w_i$ just as you did, but I got confused on the process of writing. I will try to prove that way. Once again, thank you! If you post this as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: I am saying "normally convergent" because this is in the context of normed spaces, so the norm you define on $\mathbb{R}$ could be different from the absolute value of real numbers, even though every norm defined on a finite dimentional space is equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach doesn't work as written because $x_iy_i$ might be negative.

It can be fixed, however.

The key is the theorems:

> **Theorem 1:** If $u_i$ is a sequence such of real (or complex) numbers such that $\sum_{i} |u_i|$ converges, then $\sum_i u_i$ converges.

and

> **Theorem 2:** If $u_i,v_i$ are two sequences of real numbers with $0\leq u_i\leq v_i$ and $\sum v_i$ converges, then $\sum u_i$ converges,

Then we prove that $\sum |x_iy_i|$ converges.

Let $$z_i=\max(|x_i|,|y_i|)\\w_i=\min(|x_i|,|y_i|)$$ Then, since $0\leq w_i^2\leq x_i^2,$ and $\sum x_i^2$ converges, by Theorem 2, $\sum w_i^2$ converges.

But then $z_i^2=x_i^2+y_i^2-w_i^2,$ so $\sum z_i^2$ converges.

Since, $0\leq|x_iy_i|\leq z_i^2,$ we deduce again from Theorem 2, that $\sum |x_iy_i|$ converges.

But then, by Theorem 1, $\sum x_iy_i$ converges.

---

As commenters noted, the traditional proof uses the inequality:

$$|xy|\leq \frac{x^2+y^2}{2},$$ which follows from the AM/GM inequality, or can be proven directly by expanding $$(x\pm y)^2\geq 0$$ and re-arrange.

Comment: There is one tiny little imprecision on your answer. Theorem 1 only works for complete metric spaces. Because you can take the space of polynomials $\mathcal{P}[0,1]$ defined on $[0,1]$, then take the sequence $p_n = \frac{x^n}{n!}$. The series defined by this sequence converges normally because $\|\frac{x^n}{n!}\| \leq \frac{1}{n!} \implies \sum\|\frac{x^n}{n!}\| = e$, but $\sum \frac{x^n}{n!} = e^x$ which is not a polynomial. So $p_n$ converges normally but do not converge on $\mathcal{P}[0,1]$.

Comment: Sure. Given that OP was using $\leq,$ I assumed the question was in the context of the real numbers, not some other ring. In reality, when dealing with $\ell^2$ on other rings, we write $\sum |x_i|^2$ for the norm.